# How can I restore my Delphi associations without re-installing the IDE?

Tags: delphi

Today I lost my Delphi-2007 associations; does any way exist to restore my Delphi file associations (.pas, .dpk, etc) without running the installer of Delphi?

Comment: DelphiDistiller can do that for you

Comment: Questions like this probably better fit in on http://superuser.com/. I can't see what this has to do with programming or software development.

Comment: @Smasher: This question is on topic here. Delphi is an IDE (as well as a language), and questions about IDEs are fine. (See the many many posts about Visual Studio for an example, or Eclipse.)

Comment: Your answer describes how to setup file associations in Windows. How is that related to programming? Never mind, i have no problems with such questions. I just wanted to point out that he might get better answers on superuser for topics like that.

Comment: At the very least it's an edge case, ala *"How to configure my development tool to do x"*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Type `assoc /?` at a command prompt. This will show you how to associate file extensions with file types.

If the basic registry is not corrupted, you can use `assoc *.pas BSD.pasfile` to reconnect Delphi 2007 with Pascal source files. Repeat the above with the other file types to reconnect them:

```
assoc *.dpk BDS.dpkfile
assoc *.dfm BDS.dfmfile
```

and so forth.

If this is too much work, use the registry repair option in the D2007 installer.

Comment: @Marjan: You can do anything from the command prompt. Some other goodies to try include `tasklist`, `taskkill`, `powercfg`, `shutdown`, `net`, `comp`, `find`, `findstr`, `reg`, `replace`, `where`, and `whoami`.

Answer (score 5):

i will suggest looking for a `Repair` option in **Add/Remove Programs**.

i know that the version of Delphi i use has a "Registry only" install to fix per-user issues.

Can also try a **System Restore** to the point in time before you screwed it up.

Finally you can just manually re-create the associations (**Open With...**)

Comment: If manually re-creating associations, it is best to associate with (iirc) BDSLAUNCHER.exe, as this will correctly handle existing instances.

Comment: +1 for stating the obvious and naïve solution (Open With...).

Answer (score 3):

Newer Delphi versions (verified for 10.3+) allow setting IDE file associations through Options -> File Association menu.

You can select all Delphi related or some specific extensions. Don't forget to press Save when closing the dialog to apply extension change.

Note: If you have multiple Delphi versions installed, you can only associate single IDE.

[image: File Association Options Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Usually quicker than 'Open with':

In Win 7:

Paste into the address field at the top of the window: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations

In XP:

My Computer->Tools->Folder Options-> File Types