# how to associate .dpr extension in RadStudio XE3 option?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

My Rad Studio cant open default extension (like `dpr`, `dproj` , `pas` ). How i can associate these extensions in the `RAD Studio XE3` option? I search in the `Tools->Options` but i don't find path for do that.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a [`similar question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6234003/960757) asked for Delphi 2007.

Comment: @TLama, Its seems to be they need put a way for associate files in the option without Re-Installing or hacking ways.Hope to see that feature in next version of Rad Studio!

Comment: @return How did you lose the association? I think you'll wait a long time for the feature you yearn for. I for one hope they don't spend developer effort on something like that!

Comment: @David, I just make a new user account in my windows, Remove that user account i had installed `Rad Studio` on it.After, login to new user account i lose the association!As i said,They need put a way for associate files in the option without Re-Installing or hacking ways.I remember `DelphiDistiller` was cool for do that,So `admin rights` isn't problems for them.I don't think so put this feature be really hard,spend many resources for Embarcadero :)

Comment: Well I think it unlikely they'll go out of their way to cater for that scenario. You can work around it easy enought by saving away a .reg file with the associations before you delete your user accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge this into your registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.DPR]
@="BDS.DprFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\BDS.DprFile]
@="Delphi Project File"
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,6f,00,6e,00,50,\
  00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,\
  5c,00,45,00,6d,00,62,00,61,00,72,00,63,00,61,00,64,00,65,00,72,00,6f,00,5c,\
  00,53,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,5c,00,42,00,44,00,53,00,53,00,52,00,2e,00,\
  64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,31,00,37,00,30,00,39,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\BDS.DprFile\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\RAD Studio\\10.0\\Bin\\delphicoreide170.bpl\",3"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\BDS.DprFile\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\BDS.DprFile\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\BDS.DprFile\Shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\RAD Studio\\10.0\\Bin\\bdsLauncher.exe\" \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\RAD Studio\\10.0\\Bin\\bds.exe\" /np"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\BDS.DprFile\Shell\Open\ddeexec]
@="[open(\"%1\")]"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\BDS.DprFile\Shell\Open\ddeexec\application]
@="bdslauncher"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\BDS.DprFile\Shell\Open\ddeexec\topic]
@="system"
```

Obviously this assumes your XE3 lives in the same place as mine. If it's elsewhere on your machine, then update the paths accordingly.

This is probably easier than an wholesale re-install.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks David.I Knew this way. but I'm kinda surprised when i thought there is no way in the RAD Studio development suite's option. :-o

Comment: The associations are set up by the installer. They need admin rights. Makes sense to implement them once only. Certainly my program only sets up associations in the installer.