Can I install 2 versions of RAD Studio on the same computer?
I want to install an old version of RAD Studio onto a computer that has a later version already installed.  Is there a way to do that (other than having a second Windows installation on a new disk that is used only for the old version) which does not corrupt license info in C:\ProgramData\Embarcadero?

Yes, you can install all major versions in parallel. You can also backup content of the ProgramData\Embarcadero folder to restore licenses if needed. Just copy the whole folder somewhere.

Be aware that all Delphi file types will be associated with the last installed version, in your case the older version then! To fix this you can use this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234003/how-can-i-restore-my-delphi-associations-without-re-installing-the-ide
